# Stop Opportunities (or other standard SObject) from appearing in search results

Tags: search

I know I can stop custom SObjects from appearing in the search results by not having a tab for that type. Is there a way to stop Opportunities from being 'searchable'?

The reason is is that I have a customer who has opportunities set as viewable by owner only, with a 'shadow copy' of certain information available to all users (view all checked in profiles). When searching is done via the global search the matching results from both the Opportunities and the custom sObject are shown. I'd like to show the SObject results only.

Answer (score 0):

I think that if you set the Profile security to "Tab Hidden" the users will still be able to navigate to opps from some direct links (Account rel. list, reports)... Bit cumbersome though. Alternatively hide them from the app(s) set of tabs?

You could tell the users to pin the custom object in the search preferences? I think eventually it learns and stops showing the search results from the objects you didn't click into.

Comment: Navigating to the opps is fine as the standard SFDC security permissions allow/deny access as necessary. Hiding the tab doesn't stop the Opps appearing in the search results sadly.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is in 'Sharing Rules'

> The reason is is that I have a customer who has opportunities set as
>   viewable by owner only,

For this, you should set the Organisation Wide Sharing Rule to Private.

> with a 'shadow copy' of certain information available to all users

For this, you should write a trigger to copy over the data from the opportunity to a custom object and keep it in sycn whenever the opportunity is updated, and then set the Sharing Rule for this Custom Object to 'Public Read Only'

Correct me if I am wrong, but If I understood the scenario correctly, you have all the users set to 'view all data'. I would recommend against this as this is not generally considered good practise.